# Multi-level menu items in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, slds

I am trying to display a multi-level menu in a LWC. The button menu component(lightning-button-menu) does not seem to support more than one level.

However in SLDS i see you could get that with the different style classes. Is there a way to achieve the same using lwc components?

Appreciate any help.

[image]